# Solving for specific entries in a Lyapunov Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, control-theory

Let $A$ be a $2n\times 2n$ real matrix with the following structure 
\begin{equation}
A = \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & -I \\
K & S
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{equation}
with all sub-matrices of size $n\times n$: $I$ is the identity matrix, $K$ is symmetric positive definite and $S$ is diagonal but singular. I am interested in the (numerical) solution of the  continuous time Lyapunov equation for the $2n\times 2n$ matrix R:
\begin{equation} 
R A^\text{T} + A R = \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & \Gamma
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma$ is a diagonal and singular $n\times n$ real matrix.

However, I only need a few elements of $R$. More specifically, writing

\begin{equation}
R = \left(\begin{matrix}
X & C \\
C^\text{T} & V
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{equation}
all I really want are the diagonal entries of $V$ (also $n\times n$).

Is there anyway I could reduce this problem to some other (probably Sylvester) equation for $V$ or, better yet, only it's diagonal? I don't really know how to approach this problem.

Comment: what is $C$?what kind of matrix

Comment: The solution of the Lyapunov equation, $R$, will be symmetric and positive definite (it is actually a covariance matrix). What I can prove is that $C$ is anti-symmetric ($C^\text{T} = -C$)

Comment: put instead of $C^T$ ;$-C$ if you get identity ,then it should solve problem

Comment: @dato, Sorry I don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just doing the matrix multiplications gives four equations:
$$\begin{align}
C^T = -C \\
XK + CS &= V \\
KX - SC &= V \\
KC - CK + VS + SV &= \Gamma
\end{align}$$
the last equation of course gives $VS + SV = \Gamma - KC + CK$, so if we know what $C$ is we get a Sylvester equation for $V$. If we substitute the LHS of the second and third equation in place for $V$ in the fourth equation we get:
$$K(XS + C) + (SX - C)K=\Gamma$$
and assuming $X$ is symmetric, we get $(XS + C)^T = SX - C$, so setting $B = XS + C$, the equation turns into
$$KB + B^TK = \Gamma$$
which we want to solve for $B$. Now, this is not really a standard Sylvester equations since the matrix we seek is transposed, but there are methods to solve these kinds of equations too.

Once $B$ has been found we get
$$C = \frac{1}{2}(B-B^T).$$
Since $B$ is the sum of one antisymmetric ($C$) and one symmetric matrix ($XS$), the antisymmetric part of $B$ has to be $C$.

Thus, one can now calculate the RHS in 
$$VS + SV = \Gamma - KC + CK$$
and then solve for $V$ as a standard Sylvester equation.

So, using this method you just solve two $n \times n$ Sylvester-ish equations instead of one $2n \times 2n$ equation. There might be something smarter lurking in here but I have not found it yet.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you! I'll start testing this idea right away and post some results as soon as they come out.

Comment: Actually, I have been looking at the web and haven't yet found a method for solving the eq. for B. Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: Try this article: H. W. Braden, *The Equations $A^TX \pm X^TA = B$*, SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl. Vol. 20, No. 2, pp. 295-302.